Setting up macvlan and multiple containers on Synology 7.2 saying IP is already in use
I'm setting up Unifi Network Application on my Synology with DSM 7.2 in Container Manager and a macvlan, but im running into issues. I'm using a docker-compose file to set it all up.
The local network is 192.168.1.x. The gateway is 192.168.1.138. I've setup all the folders.
Ive also set the following in both containers;
networks:
  unifi_macvlan:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.1.203

Mongo db is listening on 192.168.1.203, and the Unifi Network Application is listening on
192.168.1.203.
docker-compose:
version: "2.1"
services:
  unifi-db:
    image: mongo:4.4.18
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: unifi
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      unifi_macvlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.203
    volumes:
      - ./unificontroller/mongo/data:/data/db
      - ./unificontroller/mongo/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
  unifi-network-application:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-network-application:latest
    container_name: unifi-network-application
    environment:
      - PUID=1026
      - PGID=100
      - TZ=Australia/Sydney
      - MONGO_USER=test
      - MONGO_PASS=test
      - MONGO_HOST=unifi-db
      - MONGO_PORT=27017
      - MONGO_DBNAME=unifi
      - MEM_LIMIT=1024 #optional
      - MEM_STARTUP=1024 #optional
      - MONGO_TLS=False #optional
      - MONGO_AUTHSOURCE= #optional
    networks:
      unifi_macvlan:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.203
    volumes:
      - ./unificontroller/config:/config
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
      - 3478:3478/udp
      - 10001:10001/udp
      - 8080:8080
      - 8082:8080
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  unifi_macvlan:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ovs_eth0
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.1.138

It returns the error The IP is already in use. Looking in my network, its a free IP address, there isn't anything listening on it. I cant figure it out.
